# Python: Toggle a while loop with the same hotkey without exiting the code

Tags: python

I am trying create something like a "spam bot" (for educational purpose).
I want it something like this:
When I press a key on my keyboard (e.g.: f1), the function (while loop) should keep looping and stop only when I press the same key again (In this example: f1).
Here's a code I made...

```
import pyautogui
from pynput import keyboard
import time
import threading

text = pyautogui.prompt('Text: ')
def text():
    while running:
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        pyautogui.write(text)
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        time.sleep(3)

def on_press(key):
    global running
    if key == keyboard.Key.f1:
        running = True
        t = threading.Thread(target=text)
        t.start()
    if key == keyboard.Key.f2:
        return False

def on_release(key):
    global running
    if key == keyboard.Key.f2:
        running = False
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

However, this code uses 2 different keys to start/stop (f1 & f2) and it exits the program when I press f2.
Is it possible to use only 1 key to toggle start/stop?
Also, I don't want to exit the program when I press the "stop" key, I want it to keep running (being able to start/stop the loop whenever I want without exiting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use your `running` variable as a simple state machine with just two states:

```py
running = False

def on_press(key):
    global running
    if key == keyboard.Key.f1:
        running ^= True
        if running:
            t = threading.Thread(target=text)
            t.start()
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped me a lot. However, I think you mistyped something. I think it is supposed to be "target=spam" instead of "target=text".

Comment: What is `spam`? You get the user to input `text` and you use that in your code.

Comment: Btw, in the code you wrote (line 6): What does the "^=" symbol do? I know it stands for "running = running ^ True",
but what's the use of it? (What did it change in the code)

Comment: The line: `running ^= True` simply inverts the value in `running`. Its just less to type than: `running = running ^ True`